# In ServiceStack, how do I broadcast messages from the Server?

Tags: c#, servicestack

Is there a simple tutorial showing how to use Server Events with ServiceStack?  Specifically, I'm looking for a way to have a server generate messages to be broadcast to all clients.

I've been reading the ServiceStack [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) and playing with the sample [Chat](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat) application but neither source is very informative.  The documentation has gaps and the chat application is bloated and only shows how to send messages triggered by the client, not by the server and I can't figure out how to adapt that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Server Events Docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events#sending-server-events) shows the different APIs available for publishing Server Events:

```
public interface IServerEvents : IDisposable
{
    // External API's
    void NotifyAll(string selector, object message);
    void NotifyChannel(string channel, string selector, object message);
    void NotifySubscription(string subscriptionId, string selector, object message, string channel = null);
    void NotifyUserId(string userId, string selector, object message, string channel = null);
    void NotifyUserName(string userName, string selector, object message, string channel = null);
    void NotifySession(string sspid, string selector, object message, string channel = null);
    //..
}
```

So you can use the `NotifyAll` API to send a message to all subscribers, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IServerEvents ServerEvents { get; set; }

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        ServerEvents.NotifyAll("cmd.mybroadcast", request);
        ...
    }
}
```

Which since it's using a `cmd.*` selector, it can be [handled in JavaScript clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JavaScript-Server-Events-Client#selectors) with:

```
$(source).handleServerEvents({
    handlers: {
        mybroadcast: function(msg,e) { ... }
    }
});
```

However it should be rare that you want to send a message to all Subscribers instead of just the Subscribers in your channel.

### Server Event Examples

All JavaScript Server Event handlers in ServiceStack's reference Chat App is [captured in 40 lines of JavaScript](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/master/src/Chat/default.cshtml#L112-L152) and only [2 ServiceStack Services on the Server](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/bb49ddc3547b1dc94d3fad5c14686dbec0fb5f96/src/Chat/Global.asax.cs#L168-L238) and showcases most of the features in [JavaScript Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JavaScript-Server-Events-Client).

If the Chat App isn't clear have a look at the other [Server Event Examples](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events#serverevent-examples), e.g. the [Real-time Networked Time Traveller](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/typescript-redux#example-9---real-time-networked-time-traveller) goes through and explains how it uses Server Events to remote control all apps that are watching the Users App.

Comment: What is the code on the server-side that I can use to send out a message to all subscribers?  Where do I call `NotifyAll("selector", msg)`?  Using the Chat example, I thought it'd be in the `ServerEventsServices` class that extends `Service`, but I found that it's only instantiated when a client sends a message, and it's disposed right after the `Any(...)` is called.  Is there a way to broadcast a message from the class that extends `AppHostBase`?

Comment: @user2023861 I provided an example of the Server code above, the `IServerEvents` is just another dependency, you can call it in your own Services as shown above. [ServerEventsServices](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/master/src/Chat/Global.asax.cs#L162) is not a special class, it's just what the Chat App called its Service class. `AppHostBase` is your AppHost its where you define configuration to be initialized on Startup, you can't send events before the AppHost is initialized, there aren't any subscribers.

Comment: @user2023861 At anytime after your AppHost is initialized you can access the `IServerEvents` dependency with `HostContext.TryResolve<IServerEvents>()` and call whichever API's you want, e.g. in a [Request or Response Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) but you're normally publishing events in your own Services.

Comment: that's the part i was missing.  I didn't know if or how IServerEvents was available to use in the AppHostBase extending class.